# Espresso test case failing

Tags: android-espresso

Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'with text color: "#FF8FA2AE"' doesn't match the selected view. Expected: with text color: "#FF8FA2AE"

I am trying to find why the espresso test case is failing when I am launching in emulator even though expected text is same any idea ?